# ¿Como puedo migrar esta consulta sql a laravel eloquent?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Estoy necesitando pasar esta consulta sql a laravel eloquet, la cual en el select, quiero que me valide el ultimo registro por documento.

```
SELECT  distinct document, regDate
FROM test_SIG.employees_test p where regDate = (
    SELECT
        e.regDate
    FROM test_SIG.employees_test e
    WHERE e.document = p.document order by id desc limit 1
) group by p.document
```

Hasta el momento he hecho esta consulta con mas datos:

```
 $employees = Employee::select(
            'document AS id',
            DB::raw('IFNULL(CONCAT(name, " ", lastname), name) AS text'),
            'position',
            'email',
            'centro_trabajo',
            'city',
            'state',
            'region',
            'customer_id',
            'unidad_organizativa',
            'tipo_servicio',
            'sociedad1');

        $employees->where("regdate", "=", function($query){
            $query->select("regdate")
            ->where("document", "=", "id")
            ->limit(1)
            ->orderBy("id","desc");
        });

        if(isset($params['customer_id'])){
            $employees->where('customer_id',$params['customer_id']);
        }
        $employees->distinct('document');

        $employees = $employees->get()->keyBy('id')->toArray();
```

Pero en la subconsulta del `where "regdate"` no me reconoce el alias del `documento` llamado `id`.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado al momento?, es importante muestres que llevas avanzado

Comment: Ya lo acabo de actualizar

Comment: Aquí `->where("document", "=", "id")` quieres comparar el valor de la columna 'document' con el string `id`, o quieres comparar los valores de ambas columnas?